# Need Help Optimizing DAX Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a complex DAX measure that runs on a filtered dataset but becomes unusable on the full dataset. The calculations are accurate, but I need to optimize it for performance.

**The Problem**

Here is the error I get when trying to run it on the full dataset:

[image]

However, when I use some filters, it works as intended:
[image]

[image]

In the screenshot above, the numbers on the side represent customer ids. The numbers in the values section of the matrix are indicators showing when a customer is counted in the ‘beginning balance’ or ‘new sale’, etc.

The matrix acts as a type of ledger table that tracks when a customer is considered active or inactive.

- **Begin Balance** means that a customer is active as of the first of the month.
- **New Start** means that a customer became a new member or returning member during that month.
- **Canceled** and **Expired** indicate that a customer is no longer    active within that month.
- **End balance** means that the customer is active as of the end of    the month.

The ledger works by the following formula
**Begin Balance + New Start - Canceleld - Expired = End Balance.**

Each measure is built similarly, so I will choose the Expired measure since it is the most complex.

Here is an explanation of what the measure does:

**Variables Defined:**

- **MaxDate**: Calculates the maximum date in the Calendar table.
- **CurrentMonthStart**: Calculates the start date of the current month based on MaxDate.
- **CurrentMonthEnd**: Calculates the end date of the current month based on MaxDate.
- **AgreementsByCustomer**: Creates a summarized table of the 'Service Agreement' table, removing any filters on the Calendar table.
- **FilteredAgreements**: Adds a new column "AgreementType" to AgreementsByCustomer based on various conditions related to the
  agreement's start and end dates.
- **PreviousAgreements, CurrentAgreements, FutureAgreements**: Filters FilteredAgreements based on the "AgreementType" to create subsets of
  agreements.
- **IterationTable**: Adds two new columns to CurrentAgreements:
- **PreviousActiveAgreement**: Checks if there are any previous agreements that are still active.

**FutureActiveAgreement**: Checks if there are any future agreements that will become active.

**Main Calculation:**

**Result**: Counts the number of rows in a filtered version of IterationTable where both PreviousActiveAgreement and FutureActiveAgreement are 0, grouped by Location Sk.

**What it Ultimately Does:**
The measure calculates the number of service agreements that are considered "Expired" based on the following conditions:

The agreement is current as of the latest date in the Calendar table.
There are no previous agreements that are still active.
There are no future agreements that will become active.
The result is a count of such "Expired" agreements, grouped by Location Sk.

**Here is a link to the much smaller sample version of my model [PBIX file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgduPldv9bhEgcwyfUQaY7OKmvJl-Q?e=Kcicme)**

**DAX CODE**

```
# Expired = VAR MaxDate = CALCULATE( MAX( Calendar[Calendar Date] ), ( Calendar ) )
VAR CurrentMonthStart = EOMONTH( MaxDate, -1 ) + 1
VAR CurrentMonthEnd = EOMONTH( MaxDate, 0 )

VAR AgreementsByCustomer =
    CALCULATETABLE(
        SUMMARIZE(
            'Service Agreement',
            'Service Agreement'[Location Sk],
            'Service Agreement'[Agreement Event Type Sk],
            'Service Agreement'[Agreement Start Date Local],
            'Service Agreement'[Agreement Expired Or Canceled Date]
        ),
        ALL( Calendar )
    )

VAR FilteredAgreements =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        AgreementsByCustomer,
        "AgreementType",
        SWITCH(
            TRUE(),
            'Service Agreement'[Agreement Start Date Local] < CurrentMonthStart &&
            'Service Agreement'[Agreement Expired Or Canceled Date] < CurrentMonthStart, "Previous",
            'Service Agreement'[Agreement Expired Or Canceled Date] >= CurrentMonthStart &&
            'Service Agreement'[Agreement Expired Or Canceled Date] <= CurrentMonthEnd &&
            'Service Agreement'[Agreement Event Type Sk] = 5, "Current",
            'Service Agreement'[Agreement Expired Or Canceled Date] > CurrentMonthEnd, "Future",
            BLANK()
        )
    )

VAR PreviousAgreements = FILTER(FilteredAgreements, [AgreementType] = "Previous")
VAR CurrentAgreements = FILTER(FilteredAgreements, [AgreementType] = "Current")
VAR FutureAgreements = FILTER(FilteredAgreements, [AgreementType] = "Future")

    VAR IterationTable =
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            CurrentAgreements,
            "PreviousActiveAgreement",
                VAR CurrentAgreementExpired = 'Service Agreement'[Agreement Expired Or Canceled Date]
                VAR LocationSk = 'Service Agreement'[Location Sk]
                VAR PreviousActiveAgreements =
                    FILTER(
                        PreviousAgreements,
                        'Service Agreement'[Location Sk] = LocationSk
                            && 'Service Agreement'[Agreement Expired Or Canceled Date] >= CurrentAgreementExpired     --If the previous agreement end comes before or on the current agreement cancel                 --TEchnically this one expired and didn't cancel 2892329
                            
                    )
                RETURN
                    IF( ISEMPTY( PreviousActiveAgreements ), 0, 1 ),
             "FutureActiveAgreement",
                --VAR FutureAgreementStart = 'Service Agreement'[Future Agreement Start Date]
                VAR CurrentAgreementExpired = 'Service Agreement'[Agreement Expired Or Canceled Date]
                VAR LocationSk = 'Service Agreement'[Location Sk]
                VAR FutureActiveAgreement =
                    FILTER(
                        FutureAgreements, --CurrentAgreements
                        'Service Agreement'[Location Sk] = LocationSk 
                            && IF( ISBLANK( 'Service Agreement'[Agreement Start Date Local] ), FALSE(), 'Service Agreement'[Agreement Start Date Local] < CurrentAgreementExpired )   --if the current agreement's future start date comes before the current agreement canceled date --Blank > 1/7/2022, IF TRUE, ROW DOESN'T GET FILTERED
                            
                    ) 
                RETURN
                    IF( ISEMPTY( FutureActiveAgreement ), 0, 1 )--, --If FutureActiveAgreement is populated, then that means there is a valid future start date and therefore a canceled event should not appear. if future start date is blank, then it will result in false.
        )
        
        
        
        
    VAR Result =
        COUNTROWS( 
            GROUPBY( FILTER( IterationTable, [PreviousActiveAgreement] = 0 && [FutureActiveAgreement] = 0 )
                , 'Service Agreement'[Location Sk]
            )
        )
        
    RETURN Result
```